# Spring MVC: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect when creating a new entity record

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Good afternoon,

I am newbie to Spring MVC. I'm stuck with the following error while running my project "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

My project has two entities, Team and Country which have a ManyToOne relationship. Both these entities map tables created in mysql database.

I started the project with only the Team entity, and sucessfuly created my classes (DAO, controller, services, etc) and jsp to create new teams.

Now, I created the class Country to relate both entities and I added a dropdown list in the "add-team-form.jsp" to select the country of the new team. This page is correctly displayed (all countries appear in the dropdown list), however, when I click "submit" to create the new team, I get the error "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

Can you please help me to identify my error? I'm guessing it's in the "add-team-form.jsp".

1 - Entity Team:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="teams")
public class Team implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "name", length = 40, nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "rating", length = 6, nullable = false)
private Integer rating;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_country", nullable = false)
private Country country;   


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Integer getRating() {
    return rating;
}
public void setRating(Integer rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}
public Country getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(Country country) {
    this.country = country;
}   
}
```

2 - Entity Country:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
public class Country implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name= "id_country", length = 6)
private String idCountry;

@Column(name = "name", length = 255, nullable = false)
private String name;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "country")
private List<Team> teams;


public String getIdCountry() {
    return idCountry;
}

public void setIdCountry(String idCountry) {
    this.idCountry = idCountry;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

My Team DAO

```
@Repository
public class TeamDAOImpl implements TeamDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Session getCurrentSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@Override
public void addTeam(Team team) {

    getCurrentSession().save(team);
}
}
```

My Team Service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TeamServiceImpl implements TeamService {

@Autowired
private TeamDAO teamDAO;

public void addTeam(Team team) {
    teamDAO.addTeam(team);      
}
```

My Team Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/team")
public class TeamController {

@Autowired
private TeamService teamService;

@Autowired
private FilterService filterService;

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addTeamPage() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("add-team-form");
    modelAndView.addObject("team", new Team());

    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addingTeam(@ModelAttribute Team team) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");

    teamService.addTeam(team);

    String message = "Team was successfully added.";
    modelAndView.addObject("message", message);

    return modelAndView;
}

@ModelAttribute("countryList")
public Map<String, String> getCountryList(){

    Map<String, String> countryList = filterService.getCountries();
    return countryList;
   }

...
}
```

My "add-team-form.jsp"

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Add team page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add team page</h1>

<form:form method="POST" 
        modelAttribute="team" 
        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/team/add.html">
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rating:</td>
        <td><form:input path="rating" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>Country</label></td>
    <td>
        <form:select path="country.idCountry">
            <form:options items="${countryList}" />
        </form:select>      
    </td>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Add" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

There is no error showing in the console of eclipse, but here is the error im receiving from the browser:

```
HTTP Status 400 -

type Status report

message

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

Comment: Can you show us full stack trace?

Comment: @TanmayDelhikar I updated the question with the the error I'm receiving from the browser, there is no error showing in the console of eclipse.

Comment: Turn up the logging to DEBUG; if using Boot, here's [how](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html). If the browser is receiving an error, there's one to be printed on the server side as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems I can see here - you are posting to add/team/add.html and not hitting your post handler. You don't need the action attribute as you're posting to the same endpoint;

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="team" >
```

Secondly your are injecting the countries as a map, so these are ID/display values which works great for key/value pairs and for binding a value to a string field. In this case, Spring is trying to bind your country ID (String) to the team.country(Country) field which will fail. To help Spring out you need a databinder; in your controller add;

```
@InitBinder 
public void initBinder (WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Country.class, new CountryEditor());
}
```

and create the property editor class;

```
public class CountryEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        super.setValue(value);
    }

    public String getAsText() {
        if (getValue() == null) return null;
        return ((Country) getValue()).getName();
    };

    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (text != null) {
            Country country = // something like filterService.getCountryById(text);
            setValue(country);
        }
    };
}
```

There's more information in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

The error you are receiving generally happens if a parameter is missing or is in a different format and cannot be converted to the expected type.Check the values being passed to the Team object.You can either log the request and response or set the log level to "DEBUG",this will display the exact error in logs.